# Can't access database on HTC Amaze

Tags: android, database

I'm attempting to copy the database located, as an example, in:

```
/data/data/com.x.x.x/databases/mydb.db
```

This works on almost every phone I've tried, except for my new HTC amaze.  When trying to use ADB to assert that the database is there, it returns false when I use the `File.exists()` method in the java code.  It's the same exact code and APK, just used on different devices.

There is no logcat error, it's just that the File.exists() method returns false.  When I try to use ADB to look for the database, it says I don't have read permission.

I'm trying to back up the database by moving it to the SD card.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) to get the path to a database file. Do not assume that it is in the location you specified.

> When I try to use ADB to look for the database, it says I don't have read permission.

You cannot access `/data` on non-rooted devices via `adb`/DDMS.

Comment: Yup, that was it.  The HTC Amaze didn't like the direction of my slashes (directory separators).  I didn't know about the `getDatabasePath()` method, cheers.

Comment: @John: "The HTC Amaze didn't like the direction of my slashes (directory separators)" -- gadzooks! The Amaze runs Windows! :-)